# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutiny.SessionFactory bean not found. Hibernate Reactive with Panache

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, reactive, quarkus-panache

I'm Trying to create a CRUD implementation using hibernate reactive with Panache when I run the add method I get the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutiny.SessionFactory bean not found.

Bellow is my code:

DtoItem

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DtoItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
}
```

DaoItem:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DaoItem implements PanacheRepository<DtoItem> {

}
```

DalItem:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DalItem {

    @Inject
    DaoItem daoItem;

    public Uni<DtoItem> save(DtoItem item) {
        return daoItem.persist(item);
    }

    public Uni<DtoItem> find(Long id) {
        return daoItem.findById(id);
    }

    public Uni<List<DtoItem>> findAll(){
        return daoItem.listAll();
    }
}
```

ItemResource:

```
@RouteBase(path = "/v1/items", produces = ReactiveRoutes.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = ReactiveRoutes.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ItemResource {

    @Inject
    private DalItem dalItem;


    @Route(path = "/:id", methods = Route.HttpMethod.GET)
    public Uni<JsonObject> getSingleItem(RoutingExchange routingExchange) {
        String id = routingExchange.getParam("id").orElse("0");
        return dalItem.find(Long.parseLong(id))
                .flatMap(item -> Uni.createFrom().item(JsonObject.mapFrom(item)));
    }

    @WithTransaction
    @Route(methods = Route.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Uni<JsonObject> add(@Body DtoItem item) {
        return dalItem.save(item).flatMap(itm -> Uni.createFrom().item(JsonObject.mapFrom(itm)));
    }
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Where is your SessionFactory bean configuration ?

Comment: I don't have that defined, I'm new to the framework with limited knowledge of how it works..Kindly assist thanks

Comment: you should have an configuration (xml or java based) to define the beans, do you have any xml or java configuration ?

Comment: No I don't have any configuration, can you share a link to any resource with such configuration so that I can see how it works?

Comment: you can check this link : https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-configuration

Comment: I used the properties file configuration and it didn't work. I think it's important to note that it is Hibernate reactive, not sure if it makes use of JDBC. However I have some hibernate configurations on my application.properties file

# Hibernate Reactive configuration
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.datasource=default-reactive

Comment: Hibernate Reactive configuration might be similar to traditional Hibernate configuration, the error that you get indicate that there is no SessionFactory bean, so you need to add it, and this bean need configuration that can be different for Hibernate reactive by adding some additional properties, you can check also this link : https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-reactive-getting-started-guide/

Comment: I think you are missing a dependency.
What version of Quarkus are you using?
Can you add the list of dependencies to your post ?